# jQuery cycle not working

Tags: jquery, cycle

My structure:

```
<div class="main">
<div class="main-contents">
<img>...</img>
<img>...</img>
<img>...</img>
<img>...</img>
<img>...</img>
</div>
</div>
```

And my js code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.main .maincontents').cycle({
        fx: 'fade'
    });
});
```

But cycle don't working. When i check via Firebug, not seen an error. How can i fix it?

Comment: "main-contents" vs "maincontent"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a catch in your code:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.main .main-contents').cycle({
        //-------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^-------------change it like this
            fx: 'fade'
        });
    });
```

although you can do it like this if you concern about performance:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.main').find('.main-contents').cycle({
        //-------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^-------------change it like this
            fx: 'fade'
        });
    });
```

You have not mentioned that you have included jQuery before this script or not so try using the `CDN hosted` script for better pageLoad performance:

```
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

then after this put all your cycle script below it.

Try this and see if this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Change `jQuery('.main .maincontent')` to:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
           jQuery('.main .main-contents').cycle({ fx: 'fade' });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

your class name is wrong in JQUERY

you have mentioned .maincontent. Try this,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.main .main-contents').cycle({
        fx: 'fade'
    });
});
```